# webhook doesn't receive event from m.me link

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, reference, facebook-webhooks

I've been trying to pass parameter using m.me link, but when tester/ developer account of my app tried this feature, my webhook didn't receive any event.
My bot already has a get started button and the page is published.

what im trying to ask is why couldn't i get any event and how to solve this problem?

```
let message = {
                "attachment": {
                  "type": "template",
                  "payload": {
                    "template_type": "generic",
                    "elements": [
                      {
                        "title": "Share me ",
                        "subtitle": "share to your friend",
                        "image_url": "https://gallery.yopriceville.com/var/resizes/Free-Clipart-Pictures/Sun-and-Moon-PNG/Transparent_Sun_with_Shades_PNG_Clipart_Picture.png?m=1434276589",
                        "buttons": [
                          {
                            "type": "element_share",
                            "share_contents": {
                              "attachment": {
                                "type": "template",
                                "payload": {
                                  "template_type": "generic",
                                  "elements": [
                                    {
                                      "title": "Add to connect to your friend",
                                      "subtitle": "connect",
                                      "image_url": output.profile_pic,
                                      "default_action": {
                                        "type": "web_url",
                                        "url": `http://m.me/${page_id}?ref=invited_by_${recipientId}`
                                      },
                                      "buttons": [
                                        {
                                          "type": "web_url",
                                          "url": `http://m.me/${page_id}?ref=invited_by_${recipientId}`,
                                          "title": `ADD ${output.first_name}`
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              };
```

Comment: show us the code you are using for sending messages to webhook

Comment: I only use messenger share button template on my message. Do I need more than that? @NikhilSavaliya

Comment: webhook is listing any other events or having problem with this only?

Comment: webhook gets all events except for this m.me referral event.

Comment: I suggest you to look at above payload you are sending there may be issue with that